# Why git authentications works through SSH keys?

Tags: git, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

Question in the title, but let me detail more. Excluding the ID/Password method on git CLI, we generate a SSH key and add the public key to the remote server. Why don't we have SSH-less public-key cryptography methods? We are not even connecting to remote a machine's terminal, we don't even need to connect a remote machine's terminal (do we?), so why is it named as SSH key? Is it just about naming convention, or something else? What is the history behind that?

Comment: Read `man git-shell` to clear up some confusion.

Comment: `ssh` is both the name of a transport protocol (RFC 4253) and of the secure remote shell which runs on top of that transport.  In this case, you are using `ssh` transport (RFC 4253) and `ssh` authentication (RFC 4252) to establish a secure authenticated network connection to your `git` server, even though you are not running a login shell (roughly RFC 4254) on the remote machine.  Of course, you have other transport options as well (https) where you would _not_ use ssh keys.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33846856/2072269 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3248779/2072269

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really a question about underlying protocols of a software development tool and not unix/Linux. It might be better placed on stackoverflow or superuser but, as has already been pointed out, it may be duplicate of stackoverflow questions

Comment: Thank you @user4556274 Panki and muru, those explained a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one StackOverflow answer says (mentioned in a comment), early in Git's history the ssh protocol had the benefits of supporting both read and write access to the backend repo, as well as cryptographically strong authentication and encryption.

Another benefit of ssh is it allows managing/replacing the keys independently of your deploy software.  I.e., your deploy scripts don't have to know how to read the auth token from somewhere and and deliver it to the server.

There certainly are other protocols with comparable functionality, but these are among the reasons that git+ssh became so widely used over the past 10+ years.